# Prove $u, \Delta u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $u \in H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: integration, analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $k=2$ throughout.

Let $u, \Delta u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $u \in H^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $H^k= \{u  \in S'(\mathbb{R}^n): (1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac{k}{2}} \widehat u \in L^2\}$.

I am a bit unsure about my answer so I'd appreciate any feedback:

By Plancherel's theorem and the Fourier differentiation rules $ \Delta u \in L^2 \implies \widehat{ \Delta u} = -|\xi|^2 \widehat u  \in L^2$. But $\widehat u \in L^2$, again by Plancherel, so $(1+|\xi|^2) \widehat u \in L^2$, which concludes the proof.

Comment: Is it $k  = 2 $ ?

Comment: Of course, sorry! It is $k=2$. Just forgot to say!

Comment: Then yes, your proof is perfect.

Comment: Thank you very much!